# Copy to SD Card changes the Execute permissions (Linux)

Tags: linux, copy, sd-card, rights

I have a file on /tmp

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         6782 Jun 30 11:20 DATA_00.csv
```

when I copy it to SD Card with

```
cp /tmp/DATA_00.csv /mnt/mmccard/
```

Its Execute flag is set !

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         6782 Jun 30 11:21 DATA_00.csv
```

Is it normal ?

on Linux 2.6.20 ;)

---

@koyaanisqatsi
Hi, I don't have new information with fdisk -l
In fact I don't know why there is not only one partition.

```
/mnt/mmccard type vfat (rw,sync,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1)

Disk /dev/mmcblk0p1: 8064 MB, 8064598016 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 246112 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

          Device Boot    Start       End    Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1p1   ?    29216898    55800336   850670010+  7a  Unknown
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/mmcblk0p1p2   ?    25540106    55528404   959625529   72  Unknown
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/mmcblk0p1p3   ?           1           1           0    0  Empty
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/mmcblk0p1p4          438273      438279         221    0  Empty
Partition 4 does not end on cylinder boundary.
```

This was formatted with w10 as FAT32

Answer (score 1):

#### Hello

> Yes - Depending on the filesystem the SD Card has. I guess somewhat
> like MS FAT16/FAT32?

Check out the command `mount` without any option/parameter.

Comment: The disk is mounted with VFAT. As permissions are not managed it defaults to 'x', if I correctly understand ?

Comment: Half way ;-) - I am not really sure but vfat include different FAT types. But not including NTFS. More Information about i usally "grep" with ```fdisk -l``` This is read-only and list all block devices including partitions.